# Open file with path needing character escaping in Go

Tags: regex, string, operating-system, go

I have a file which `os.open()` gives me back, `no such file or directory`. Is there a function which can escape a file name for getting the correct  path to it? Something similar to the net package `QueryEscape` ?, but for file paths of course

Here is the Path name `"Music/3OH!3 - Streets Of Gold 2010 [Cov+CD][Bubanee]/06. Touchin On My - 30H!3.mp3"`

I'm just using a simple

```
srcName := "Music/3OH!3 - Streets Of Gold 2010 [Cov+CD][Bubanee]/06. Touchin On My - 30H!3.mp3"
src, err := os.Open(srcName)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
```

The file does exist btw, go just cant follow the path name. The path that bash can follow is `Music/3OH\!3\ -\ Streets\ Of\ Gold\ \[Cov+CD\]\[Bubanee\]/12.\ Strrets\ Of\ Gold\ -\ 30H\!3.mp3` which shows all the escaping that is needed.

Comment: Which platform? What is the cwd when you run the program? What is the full (rooted) pathname of the .mp3?

Comment: the full root is `/Users/matt/Music/3OH!3 - Streets Of Gold 2010 [Cov+CD][Bubanee]/06. Touchin On My - 30H!3.mp3`, and this is on osx.

Comment: Can you please retry opening the file using the rooted name? If it still fails then please fill an [issue report](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/list). PS: No OSX around, I cannot investigate it by myself.

Comment: I've recreated the file/dir structure you mention in your post, and it works fine on Linux (64-bit). Perhaps something else is not right. Is the program's current working directory altered somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried creating the same directory structure on my machine (Mac OS 10.8.3), and I had no trouble opening the file using your code. This means that the path is properly escaped when opening already.

Make sure you're running your go program from a location right above the `Music/` folder, or just use the full root path for `srcName`.